# Using filter() method to filter array results by substring

Tags: javascript, filter

I keep trying to pull the email addresses out of an array of links using filter by text.  This is the code I tried that is not working.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, any ideas?

```
let links = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
let subset = links.filter(getEmails);
function getEmails(email) {
    return subset.includes('@');
}
```

Comment: You need to tag questions with a language in order to not spam the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Filter doesn't work like that. The callback for the filter method gets each element.

```js
function getEmailLinks() {
  const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));
  return links
    .map((link) => link.href)
    .filter((link) => link.includes('mailto'))
    .map((link) => link.split(':')[1])
    .filter((email) => email.includes('@'));
}

console.log(getEmailLinks());
```

```html
<a href="mailto:test@testmail.com">mailto</a>
<a href="mailto:test1@testmail.com">mailto</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  do you have any alternative suggestions about how to do this, perhaps using regEx?

Comment: Usually the anchor links for emails contain mailto in it's href.
I updated my code please check if that's what you want.